# Web3 related jobs

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain

I am looking for job opportunities in the web3 space.

May I know what are some areas/ websites where I can find such jobs?

Would greatly appreciate some help here. Thanks!:)

Comment: I understand your request, but this question is too broad and might not be appropriate for this forum. You could look for web3 job boards (there are a lot of them) or join discords of popular projects to connect with opportunities. All the best for your job search!

Answer (score 0):

You may try https://ethereum.org/en/community/get-involved/#ethereum-jobs

This question isn't really for this site but answering as it benefits people rather than causing harm.